# getting a PHP result to android app with JS using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a grid with a PHP call on the server using jQuery. I either get nothing on the grid, or I get an error message.

Conexion JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'conexresumenu.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                var landmark ='<div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-c" style="width:50px">'+item.id+'</div><div class="ui-block-b ui-bar-c" style="width:80px">'+item.username+'</div><div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-c" style="width:80px">'+item.join_date+'</div><div class="ui-block-d ui-bar-c" style="width:50px">'+item.is_active+'</div>';

                output.append(landmark);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Hubo un error al cargar los datos');
        }
    });
});
```

Now the HTML file geting this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Manager</title>
<link href="cssmain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Esta referencia a phonegap.js permitirá disponer de sugerencias para el código, siempre y cuando el sitio actual se haya configurado como aplicación móvil. 
     Para configurar el sitio como aplicación móvil, vaya a Sitio -> Aplicaciones móviles -> Configurar framework de aplicación... -->

<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/resumenu.js"></script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        Users
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   

        <h3> Usuarios </h3><div id='output' class=ui-grid-c>

      <div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-c" style="width:50px">ID</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b ui-bar-c" style="width:80px">Username</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-c" style="width:80px">Alta</div>    
      <div class="ui-block-d ui-bar-c" style="width:50px">Status</div>
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and now the PHP CALL on server:

```
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);


 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, join_date, is_active FROM members", $con) or trigger_error(mysql_error());


//create an output array
$output = array();

//if the MySQL query returned any results
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {


    //iterate through the results of your query
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        //add the results of your query to the output variable
        $output[] = $row;
    }


    //send your output to the browser encoded in the JSON format
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'items' => $output));

} else {

    //if no records were found in the database then output an error message encoded in the JSON format
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'items' => $output));
}
```

Comment: What's the error say when you receive, also, anything in the console?

Comment: I agree with @tymeJV, it would be very helpful to know where your codee is breaking, on the server-side or the client-side. What is the error message you receive when you try to retrieve the content? Use your web browser's console to help you

Comment: On the server side im getting this: {"status":"success","items":[{"id":"79","username":"user1","join_date":"2013-04-30 17:06:01","is_active":"1"},{"id":"64","username":"user2","join_date":"2013-02-07 08:42:32","is_active":"1"},{"id":"76","username":"user3","join_date":"2013-04-26 10:09:33","is_active":"1"},{"id":"78","username":"user4","join_date":"2013-04-30 15:54:44","is_active":"1"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the data type to be `jsonp`. This is wrong, as you're outputting regular `json`. (`jsonp` is JSON wrapped in a function call).

**JSON**:

```
{ my: [json], goes: "here"] }
```

**JSONP**:

```
jsonpCallback({ my: [json], goes: "here"] });
```

Change `dataType` to `json` and remove the `jsonp` key.

**Edit**: You're also wrongly looping through the `data` object. You should be looping through `data.items`.

Comment: @WainmanSudamerica What didn't make sense? StackOverflow isn't a site for people to correct your code, but rather to tell you what you did wrong so you can fix it for yourself (or you'll simply be back next time because the same thing happens - and would never learn anything).

Answer (score 0):

When running JavaScript in an HTML5 container for Android. The domain is that of the app and not the web server.

To tell the web server to allow JSON responses to other domains. Add the following to the top of your PHP code.

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

This will only be a problem if you're running the JavaScript in a container like PhoneGap. Running in the Android browser like Chrome won't be a problem. The reason is that PhoneGap changes the domain so that it's localhost.

Comment: I have done this. now its giving me back:
undefined values on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. Thanks all.
The real issue was the response of the server side. It was not quite good.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');


$server = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);


 $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, join_date, is_active FROM members", $con) or trigger_error(mysql_error());



//create an output array

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

Everything else that I did is correct. Works fine. Thanks all.